# Injectors.getInjector() method is not supported in Serenity version 4.0.28

Tags: serenity

Injectors.getInjector() method is not supported in Serenity version 4.0.28 . Is there any other solution if same version i have to use ?. Thanks

I have tried with using serenity-model, but again getting same issue.

Injectors.getInjector() method is not supported in Serenity version 4.0.28 . Is there any other solution if same version i have to use ?. Thanks

I have tried with using serenity-model, but again getting same issue.